# tests/**/*.coffee not matching root files on debian

Tags: path, mocha.js

I have a project which for its tests runs:

`./node_modules/.bin/mocha tests/**/*.coffee -r coffee-script/register -c`

`tests/` looks like this:

```
_helper.coffee
database-tests.coffee
routers/
    index-router-tests.coffee
    team-router-tests.coffee
```

On my windows dev machine it works fine running `_helper.coffee` first and then the rest of the files.

On my CI server running debian it only tries to run `routers/*` missing out anything in the root folder.

I am assuming that `tests/**/*.coffee` isnt right for unix?

Comment: I have had the same problems on Windows where it is not returning the files in the same order that you see them listed on the drive.  I have therefore used tests/*.coffee and then tests/**/*.coffee

Comment: its odd on windows its fine but not debian. I have added tests/*.coffee before tests/**/*.coffee for my ci run command and its working now. Still seems odd to me why it would be happening

Comment: I found that Windows will retrieve the files in the order they were likely written to the hard drive, while a directory or other list will have them sorted for display.  This seemed to be the problem I was encountering.

Answer (score 0):

Moving Comments to an Answer for others since it appears to have fixed your problem.

I have had the same problems on Windows where it is not returning the files in the same order that you see them listed on the drive. I have therefore used tests/*.coffee and then tests/**/*.coffee.

I found that Windows will retrieve the files in the order they were likely written to the hard drive, while a directory or other list will have them sorted for display. This seemed to be the problem I was encountering.

The parent directory ('tests') does not seem to be included when using tests/** which seams to mean directories under the tests folder, and does not include the tests folder itself.

Comment: Its not the file order that's the problem, my debian box is not running the files in the `tests` directory only the files in its sub directories.

Telling it to run `tests/*.coffee` first gave it a pattern that actually made it load the files in the root of `tests/`